# What is the purpose for multiple comma-separated expressions in a WHILE condition?

Tags: javascript, syntax, coding-style

I stumbled over the following JavaScript:

**Code:**

```
var x="", i=0;
while (i<4, i<7, i<5, i<6)
{
  x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  i++;
}
document.write(x);
```

I never know that it is possible to use multiple comma-separated expression in one `WHILE` statement.

**Result:**

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
The number is 5
```

What is the reason for this and what is the behavior (only the last expression is evaluated for the while-exit)?

Is the behavior standardize in all `Javascript/C/Java` languages?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: There is _no_ good reason for writing the code that way.

Comment: Only the last one is used here (i<6). another doc: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Comment: ok... it seems to be a stupid question if you know that it is called "Comma operator" :-) thank you all :-)

Comment: It doesn't look like a stupid question, just a stupid code you should avoid. I hope it's not a kind of tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special operator in JavaScript which is called comma operator; 
so when JavaScript comes across this line

```
(i<4, i<7, i<5, i<6)
```

it will  evaluate one by one all the operands in the parenthesis and will return the evaluation of the last item i.e. `i < 6`

It is rarely used; One occasion that I remember to have used it was for indirect call to `eval`.

```
(0, eval)(src)
```

But again in you example the use of it is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

[Only the last result is kept in result of the comma operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.14), so

```
while (i<4, i<7, i<5, i<6)
```

is really equivalent to

```
while (i<6)
```

That's the reason why you don't see this more often : it's useless if your comparisons don't have side effects.

Comment: The comma operator is of course sometimes used when the expressions are actually assignments rather than comparisons, and therefore do have side effects.

Comment: @Alnitak I was more referring to comparisons having side effects without being just obvious assignments, like `while (i<nextNum(), i<nextNum())` but it's hard to come with good code using this in a while condition...

Comment: the comment wasn't really aimed at you, but at your readers ;-)